# How to set seed for random drawings with Numpy?

Tags: probability

I'm trying to set the seed for a few lines of code in a jupyter notebook.

However, when I tried running numpy.random.seed(0) in the initial cell, in the later cells the random generator was not 'seeded'. I had to write a set seed in all the cells where I was running the random draws... Why is that? Is there a way to avoid having to write the same thing in every cell where I have a random draw?

Also, I checked the [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.seed.html?highlight=random%20seed#numpy.random.seed)  and it seems that `numpy.random.seed()` is not the best practice. I don't understand the example given there... How would I go about, according to the best practices shown in the example, in order to do something similar to `numpy.random.seed(constant)`?

Comment: This seems like an artifact of running in Jupyter. If you put all of that in a .py file that you run from the command line, the seeding will remain throughout the entirety of the script.

Comment: I think asking this in the main site of stack overflow will give you an answer much faster

Comment: Is this the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51424857/numpy-random-seed-valid-for-entire-jupyter-notebook?

Comment: @Burger, yes, it is. Thanks ;)

Comment: @Gulzar thanks ;)

Comment: @Dave thanks ;)